# Diplomacy: double attack on a region

Tags: diplomacy

Diplomacy question about resolving a difficult order set:

- **French Fleet** in Tyrrhenian Sea move to Ionian Sea
- **French Fleet** in Tunis support Tyrrhenian Sea moving to Ionian Sea
- **Ottoman Fleet** in Aegan Sea move to Ionian Sea
- **Ottoman Fleet** in Eastern Mediterranean Sea support Aegan Sea moving to Ionian Sea
- **Ottoman Fleet** in Ionian Sea move to Adriatic Sea

Ottoman Fleet in Ionian Sea fails to move to Adriatic Sea due to a non important reason.

What happens?

Ionian Sea is attacked by French and Ottoman, both with a force of 2. If there was no unit, it would be a standoff.

But Ionian Sea is already occupied by an Ottoman Fleet which failed its movement, making the region defended only by one.

The Ottoman player can't dislodge its own fleet with its force 2 attack.

Does the French player, with its own force 2 attack, can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asuming the other fields are not relevant, we have the following setup:

[image]

- The fleet in ion can not moves to adr because it is blocked.
- Both the french fleet in tys as the ottoman fleet in aeg try to move to ion, both with support. Equal forces block. So both fail. Leaving the previously blocked fleet in ion unharmed.

So no unit moves. Leaving the setup unchanged.

**Note:** if the move to adr did not fail both supported moves still block eachother and the single fleet in ion stays unharmed.

In that case, the result will be:
[image]

Comment: This is a perfect answer. It's great the answer notes that whether or not the Ionian vacated at all is entirely irrelevant!  If it stays, as it did in your example, the rule to look up is "Beleaguered Garrison".

Answer (score 1):

This situation is almost verbatim one of the examples in the diplomacy rulebook (the bolding is mine):

> Support in Standoffs
>
> Diagrams 10 and 11 show two common standoff situations.  In both cases, a strength of two meets a strength of two and all units stand in place.  In diagram 10, if there had been a Fleet in the Tyrrhenian, it would not be dislodged by the standoff.  **(A standoff does not dislodge a unit already in the province where the standoff took place.)**

[image]